# Centering \inputminted inside a figure?

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, minted

I'm using `minted` package to import some code and also kind of images using ASCII art. I've wrapped the `\inputminted` with `\figure` with a caption and all works fine.

The only thing I can't accomplish is centering the ASCII art figure. I've tried:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{center}
        \inputminted[fontsize=\scriptsize]{text}{./samples/styles.txt}
    \end{center}
    \caption{Example programming styles}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: using `\begin{center}` within figures is deprecated the normal way would be to use `\centering`

Comment: @Rico thanks, but even \centering is not working...

Comment: @Rico *deprecated* is not the right word. I would rather say that using a `center` environment within a `figure` is ill-advised. See [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables).

Answer (score 6):

Pygmentize outputs a file that contains `\begin{Verbatim}` and `\end{Verbatim}` and changing this is out of the question. But we can exploit `fancyvrb`'s features:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\RecustomVerbatimEnvironment{Verbatim}{BVerbatim}{}
\inputminted[fontsize=\scriptsize]{latex}{./inpmint.tex}
\caption{Example programming styles}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I have used the LaTeX file itself for the example: the `Verbatim` environment is “recustomed” to use `BVerbatim` instead. Doing this in the `figure` environment ensures the environment will revert to its previous meaning after `\end{figure}`.

[image]

Comment: This solution makes line numbers disappear.

Comment: This solution does not only ignore the line numbers but also the autogobble option. Maybe even more minted options. I only tried these. The minted documentation also says (page 74): 
"*Getting the inline command to work correctly require redefining Verbatim to be BVerbatim temporarily. This approach would break if BVerbatim were ever redefined elsewhere.*"  Not sure if that is related.

Answer (score 0):

The other alternative would be to use the changepage package and adjustwidth environment,

```
\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{adjustwidth}{.3\textwidth}{}

\end{adjustwidth}
```

Comment: It would be good to make this answer complete (compilable) in the context of the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses a minipage of known (estimated) size to wrap the minted. And I give the example with the listing environment of the minted package but it works equally well with figures.

**Pro**: Can display line numbers from minted (unlike @egreg's solution)

**Con**: You have to know/guess/estimate the size of the longest line (easy for text that you put inside a `\begin{minted}...\end{minted}` environment directly, see below).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{listing}[H]
\centering
\begin{minipage}[t]{.7\textwidth}% !!! you have to estimate this value !!!
  \inputminted[fontsize=\scriptsize,linenos,
           firstline=4,lastline=11]{latex}{./test.tex}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Guessing the line length}
\end{listing}
% If on the other hand you use \begin{minted}...\end{minted} it is easy to
% measure the longest line with \widthof{...}:
\begin{listing}[H]
\centering
\begin{minipage}[t]{\widthof{\texttt{\scriptsize if you have all the lines in your tex file}}}
\begin{minted}[linenos,fontsize=\scriptsize]{latex}
use
\widthof{\texttt{the longest line}}
instead of
.7\textwidth
if you have all the lines in your tex file
\end{minted}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Measuring the line length}
\end{listing}
\end{document}
```

[image]