# \inputminted inside listing environment is flush left

Tags: horizontal-alignment, minted, fancyvrb

I want to include part of the following file, `foo.py`, using `\inputminted` in a `listing` environment.

```
def foo(a, b):
    return a + b

def bar(a, b)
    return a - b
```

However, if this `listing` environment occurs in some other environment that increases the indentation of the left margin, `\inputminted` does not seem to respect this.

(Note that you'll need to save the contents of the first code block as `foo.py` in the same directory as this MWE in order for it to compile.)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}

\item

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  Suspendisse euismod, orci ac iaculis posuere, felis augue ultricies augue.

  \begin{listing}[H]
    \inputminted[firstline=1,lastline=2]{python}{foo.py}
    \caption{The function foo}
  \end{listing}

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  Suspendisse euismod, orci ac iaculis posuere, felis augue ultricies augue. 

  \begin{listing}[H]
    \begin{minted}{python}
    def foo(a, b):
        return a + b
    \end{minted}
    \caption{The function foo}
  \end{listing}

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  Suspendisse euismod, orci ac iaculis posuere, felis augue ultricies augue.  

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: Picture showing the result of compiling the MWE provided here]

I believe this is related to [Centering \inputminted inside a figure?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115608/32888), but I'm not totally sure what the solution is. According to the `fancyvrb` documentation, `resetmargins` is false by default, so the margin should not have been reset, but it nonetheless appears to have been reset. How can I make sure that the margin respects other indented environments when using `\inputminted` inside of a `listing` environment? That is, I want to be able to use `\inputminted` but have the indentation of the code block that I get for the second `listing` environment when just using `\begin{minted}...\end{minted}`.

Comment: Please, where can I find foo.py? Your code have an error: `Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output; \inputminted was [...ed[firstline=1,lastline=2]{python}{foo.py}]`.

Comment: @Sebastiano Sorry, the first code block was intended to be saved as `foo.py`. I'll edit the question to make that clearer.

Comment: There's no need, at least for me, to apologize to me. I just wanted to help you :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a different approach with `\captionof`:

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.py}
def foo(a, b):
    return a + b

def bar(a, b)
    return a - b
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{showframe}% just for the example

\newenvironment{pseudolisting}
 {\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\vspace*{\topsep}}
 {\vspace*{\topsep}\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

Some text before to check the spacing
\begin{listing}[H]
  \inputminted[firstline=1,lastline=2]{python}{\jobname.py}
  \caption{The function foo}
\end{listing}
Some text after to check the spacing


\begin{enumerate}

\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Suspendisse euismod, orci ac iaculis posuere, felis augue ultricies augue.

\begin{pseudolisting}
\inputminted[firstline=1,lastline=2]{python}{\jobname.py}
\captionof{listing}{The function foo}
\end{pseudolisting}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Suspendisse euismod, orci ac iaculis posuere, felis augue ultricies augue. 

\begin{pseudolisting}
\begin{minted}{python}
def foo(a, b):
    return a + b
\end{minted}
\captionof{listing}{The function foo}
\end{pseudolisting}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Suspendisse euismod, orci ac iaculis posuere, felis augue ultricies augue.  

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Production notes.** I used `showframe` to see the page margins; the file is saved as `\jobname.py` just not to clobber my files. You may want to change `\topsep` to something else.

Comment: +1 So I take it the underlying issue has to do with how the `Verbatim` environment interacts with floats? Anyway, I'm happy with this solution, so I've gone ahead and accepted the answer. Thanks!